# FutureBuilder works fine on the debug stage but on apk build always throws error

Tags: android, json, dart, flutter, apk

I have the following code which should show a process indicator during the process of fetching a JSON data from the web. It works fine when I run in the debug mode. But as soon as I make it to an apk, the app opens and with no time delays, it throws this error:

> SocketException:

How to get rid of these issues?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Quize It Up'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCategories();
  }

  Future<List> getCategories() async {
    var url = 'https://opentdb.com/api_category.php';
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    List categories = jsonResponse["trivia_categories"];

    return categories;
  }

  Widget mainGui() {
    return Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getCategories(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> asyncSnapshot) {
              switch (asyncSnapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => getCategories(),
                  );
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (asyncSnapshot.hasData)
                    return Text(asyncSnapshot.error.toString());
                  else
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: asyncSnapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(asyncSnapshot.data[index]['name']),
                        );
                      },
                    );
              }
            }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: mainGui(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: SocketException: which get invoked only when I build the apk and run in device.

Comment: Can you post the stack traces for this?

Comment: it is a runtime error when I build the apk and run it separately.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are calling `getCategories();` in your `initState()` method for no reason. Since `getCategories()` is simply building and returning a Future that you don't use in initState this call is irrelevant. You might simply delete this line or even the entire `initState()` method.

Then this code basically does nothing:

```
case ConnectionState.none:
   return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () => getCategories(),
   );
```

In order to show a button that reloads the Future you might instead refresh the state like this. This will rebuild your widget and therefore rebuild the future.

```
case ConnectionState.none:
   return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
         setState(() {});
      },
   );
```

But anyways. If all that you want to achieve is a loading indicator while the Future is loading I'd rather observe the `hasData` attribute of the snapshot. Something like this might work:

```
return FutureBuilder (
        future: getCategories(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: asyncSnapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(asyncSnapshot.data[index]['name']),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        }
    );
```

Just for clarity. The error you are seeing is coming from this bug here:

```
case ConnectionState.done:
   if (asyncSnapshot.hasData)
      return Text(asyncSnapshot.error.toString());
```

Your saying here that if the Future is done and has some data received then you show the error instead of the data.

Comment: The thing is that this code and my above code works in debug mode but not when you build the apk and run it. In your code the spinner is moving forever.Now what is the solution

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions? Especially removing the initState() method.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

in the manifest.xml file as the latest flutter SDK has changed the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the solution was to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` , but you have to add it in the AndroidManifest.xml file in the location /android/src/main in your flutter project